# Overriding default credentials in AWS-SDK

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, sinatra, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

We have a web app which uses Amazon S3 throughout, and to facilitate ease of maintenance, we set up a distinct IAM User with the appropriate bucket permissions etc.  We pre-set the credentials for this user in the initializer section of our Ruby/Sinatra app as thus:

```
# MyS3UserIAM
Aws.config.update({
        :region => 'us-east-1',
        :credentials => Aws::Credentials.new(ENV['AWS_S3_KEY'],ENV['AWS_S3_SECRET'])
})
```

This works great, because we can instantiate S3 objects all through our code without having to re-specify the credentials each time.

The issue is, we've now added a small routine to a subsection of our site, which needs to use Amazon DynamoDB for just two calls.  We've set up a separate IAM with permissions to the DynamoDB tables, and we are creating the object as thus within the routine:

```
# MyDynamoUserIAM
mydynamodb = Aws::DynamoDB::Client.new(
  access_key_id: ENV['AWS_DYNAMO_KEY'],
  secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_DYNAMO_SECRET']
)
```

The problem is that when we try to make any query using *mydynamodb*, we get access failures saying that **MyS3UserIAM** has no permissions on our DynamoDB tables.

(In fact, the error is confusing, because the error message gives our **MyDynamoUserIAM** ARN in the error string, but displays **MyS3UserIAM** as the IAM name!)

I would have thought that specifying the credentials during the `Aws::Object` instantiation would override the `Aws.config` settings, but appears that it does not.  Is there any way to work around this?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying explicit credentials while constructing an Aws Client will override the Aws.config settings. Something else is going wrong.

I suspect the AWS_DYNAMO_KEY/AWS_DYNAMO_SECRET env variables are resolving to nil in your environment. If you pass in access_key_id: nil when constructing the client, the SDK will treat it as if you had not supplied the parameter and fall back to the credential provider chain to find credentials. Double check that the values you are getting for those match what you expect.

It's also possible that the IAM policies you have associated with that IAM user have issues. If the environment variables have the right values, please post your redacted IAM policy so that we can review it.